# implement auth route - with nested /signin and /signup routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to implement simple `signin/signup` routs with react-router-dom.

here is the  **App.js**

```
<div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Route exact path="/auth" component={SignInSignUpPage} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
```

and I'm using route guard like so :

```
const HomePage = ({ currentUser }) => {
  return currentUser ? <HomePageComponent /> : <Redirect to="/auth" />;
};
```

Now what I want to do, is to have the `/auth` route, for users to login, and inside a container of both the `signInSignUp`, I have a Link that will change the route to `auth/signup` to view the signup page like so:

```
const SignInSignUpPage = ({ match }) => {
  return (
    <SignInSignUpContainer>
      <Route path={`${match.path}`} component={SignIn} />
      <Route path={`${match.path}/signup`} component={SignUp} />
    </SignInSignUpContainer>
  );
};
```

which in turn will render the correct component :

```
const SignInSignUpContainer = ({ match, children, history }) => {
  const { isExact } = match;

  return (

      <SignInSignUpContainerContent>
        <SignInSignUpContainerContentForm>
          <LockIconContainer iconName="icon-lock-closed" />
          {children}
        </SignInSignUpContainerContentForm>
      </SignInSignUpContainerContent>
  );
};
```

I must be doing it wrong, and the react-router-dom docs are addressing the protected route, which I didn't find suitable for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just from looking at the structure: you don't send `match` prop down to `SignInSignUpContainer`, and it seems that `SignInSignUpContainer` expects it.

should be :

```
  const SignInSignUpPage = ({ match }) => {
  return (
    <SignInSignUpContainer match={match}>
      <Route path={`${match.path}`} component={SignIn} />
      <Route path={`${match.path}/signup`} component={SignUp} />
    </SignInSignUpContainer>
  );
};
```

same with `history` prop